# Post comment with Facebook PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can post in my wall , friend's wall... but i need post a comment with fabook php api, something like this:

**POST**:         Helloo!
**COMMENT**: Hi!! <-PHP facebook API

POST in my wall :

```
$facebook->api('/feed/me/', 'post', array('message' => $message)); //Script running OK
```

POST in wall friend's:

```
$facebook->api('/ID_or_username_friend/feed/', 'post', array('message' => $message)); //Script running OK
```

but if use:

```
$facebook->api('/id_post/feed/', 'post', array('message' => $comment)); // nothing happens
```

they dont show any errors, but the comment is not posted :/ if i use another method i recive:

> Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components:

any can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `$facebook->api('/id_post/comments', ...`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Post object documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments) - to add a comment to a Post you need to make a POST request to `/<POST ID>/comments`

The only parameter is `message`, with the text of the comment the user typed in